# C++ change default argument to constructor in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

Consider the class Mixer:

```
class Mixer{

    int numChannels;

    public: Mixer(int numChannels = 2):numChannels(numChannels){

    }

}
```

I have a subclass called Adder. I'd like the default of numChannels in adder to be 1. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the default value in the constructor of Adder:

```
class Adder: public Mixer {
  public:
    Adder(int numChannels = 1): Mixer(numChannels) {}
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this:

```
class Adder : Mixer
{
public:
    Adder(int numChannels = 1) : Mixer(numChannels){}
};
```

Comment: Wish I could accept both of the near-instant answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use default arguments - provide a default constructor that takes no inputs and sets it to the default you want.

Comment: Sorry been thinking in Java.  Revised to the C++ paradigm for this.